# Code segment concerning polymorphism. Why does the following result in a compilation error?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Why does the following code result in a compilation error? Since it is a GeeksforGeeks object, shouldn't it use the getValue() method found in class GeeksforGeeks. I added a getValue() method to the base class and the code compiled. What is the reasoning for this?

```
class GFG 
{ 
    protected void getData() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Inside GFG"); 
    } 
} 

class GeeksforGeeks extends GFG 
{ 
    protected void getData() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Inside GeeksforGeeks"); 
    } 

    protected void getValue() 
    { 
        System.out.println("GeeksforGeeks"); 
    } 
} 

public class Test 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        GFG obj = new GeeksforGeeks(); 
        obj.getValue(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You declare the object as a `GFG`, which does **not** contain the `getValue()` method. Parents do not inherit from their children.

Comment: It states cannot resolve method getValue();

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `getValue()` method only exists in the `GeeksForGeeks` subclass, but not in the parent class `CFG`.  And in your code, you define `obj` to be of the parent class type.

One fix here would be to just give `CFG` a `getValue()` method:

```
class GFG {
    protected void getData() {
        System.out.println("Inside GFG");
    }

    protected void getValue() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

By adding any implementation for `getValue()` to the `CFG` class, you will complete the inheritance chain, and Java should then call the overloaded version in the `GeeksForGeeks` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Reference Variable of `obj` is of Type `GFG` and that class does not have a `getValue()` Method. If you change the Reference Variable to `GeeksForGeeks` it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `obj` as a `GFG` object. `GFG` does **not** contain the `getValue()` method.

It is important to understand that parent objects do not inherit from their children. So, while `GeeksForGeeks` **is** a `GFG`, a `GFG` is **not** a `GeeksForGeeks` (just like a `Buick` **is** a `Car`, but not every `Car` is a `Buick`).

Update your line to `GeeksForGeeks obj = new GeeksForGeeks();` or move the `getValue()` method to your `GFG` class and you'll be right as rain.

---

You should think about your design a bit. Will every class that extends `GFG` need to have a `getValue()` method? If so, and they'll all do the same thing, that method belongs in the `GFG` class.

Suppose, however, that you want each child of `GFG` to run its own code when `getValue()` is called. Then you would still want `getValue()` declared in `GFG`, but you'd override it in your `GeeksForGeeks` class:

```
@Override
public void getValue(){
    // Code here
}
```

This is an overly-simplified explanation of inheritance, but should lead you in the right direction as there's much to learn on the subject.

> **Side Note:** Your `getValue()` method does not actually `return` anything; this would be a confusing implementation; what is the caller "getting" from the method?